# Why can't I see my full rbindlist result?

Tags: r, data.table, facet

I used the `rbindlist()` function to try and merge two melted data frames (`means_melt` and `means_melt_50`). I'm wondering why it comes up with the break in the data? And whether I can use the whole list as I ultimately intend to create two graphs, each with 5 sets of data (grouped by variable), and using `facet_grid()`. I want the two graphs separated based on "Accuracy".

```
> compiled_means <- list(means_melt, means_melt_50)
> rbindlist(compiled_means, use.names = TRUE, fill=FALSE, idcol = NULL)
             Divisions Accuracy variable value
   1:         1        0        mean20    16
   2:         2        0        mean20    20
   3:         3        0        mean20    21
   4:         4        0        mean20    17
   5:         5        0        mean20    20
   ---                                  
  196:        16       50       mean_2     2
  197:        17       50       mean_2     2
  198:        18       50       mean_2     2
  199:        19       50       mean_2     4
  200:        20       50       mean_2     3
```

If anyone has a more efficient way for me to format the data so that it can be put in the  graphs I want, I'm happy to hear suggestions. I'm not sure if the route I'm taking if effective or long-winded...

Comment: You might want to replace one of those tags with [tag:data.table], since it's the package that rbindlist comes from. Similarly, I'm sure `facet_grid` comes from some package you are not mentioning.

Comment: Anyway, your answer is in the FAQ for the package, item 2.11: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Thank you - I didn't actually know that these existed. I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 5):

Simply a matter of preferences and options - by default the function shows a summary of data.tables that have >100 rows. The following direct print gives the full data table.

```
print(your.data.table, nrows = Inf)
```

https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#only-the-first-10-rows-are-printed-how-do-i-print-more